# Magento display date into multi values

Tags: magento-1.9, php, date

I load the following code:

```
<?php if (isset($item['delivery_eta'])): ?>
<?php $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('m-d-Y', $item['delivery_eta']);
if (!$date) { $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $item['delivery_eta']); }
?>
<?php foreach ($this->getOutOfStockItems()->getData() as $item): ?>
    <?php echo $this->getFormatedDate($date->format('Y-m-d'), 'full') ?>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

This is displaying the date into the following output: Friday 15 December 2017

But now I need to get the php line, that only displays Friday.

How can I achieve that?

I also need the php line for only the day, in this example 15.
And also only the month, in this example December.

How can I get these values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php echo $this->getFormatedDate($date->format('Y-m-d'), 'full')['day'] ?>
```

EDIT:

**Workaround**

**To just get the date**

```
    <?php $parsedDate= $this->getFormatedDate($date->format('Y-m-d'), 'full') ?>
    <?php echo strtok($parsedDate, " ") ?> // Friday
```

**To parse all your full date separatly**

```
<?php $parsedDate= $this->getFormatedDate($date->format('Y-m-d'), 'full') ?> // Friday 15 December 2017

$parsingDate = explode(" ", $parsedDate);
echo $parsingDate[0]."<br/>"; // Friday
echo $parsingDate[1]."<br/>"; // 15
echo $parsingDate[2]."<br/>"; // December
echo $parsingDate[3]."<br/>"; // 2017
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That is only dispalying "F" instead of "Friday"

Comment: Look my update @Henk Z

Comment: Thanks, but that does not work. Because we need to change the date format from 'm-d-Y' to 'Y-m-d', this because the date format inside the attributes.

Comment: Look now @Henk Z

Comment: Thanks! But now I need the same for the name of the Month and also the Day of the Month

Comment: Look my update @Henk Z

Answer (score 0):

For only displays Friday.

you need to used this code.

```
<?php foreach ($this->getOutOfStockItems()->getData() as $item): ?>
<?php echo $this->getFormatedDate($date->format('D'), 'full') ?>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, sadly that does not seem to work. It displays a other date, instead of only Friday. It displays then Wednesday 13 December 2017 instead of Wednesday 3 January 2018.

Comment: I update answer, please check that.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That still does not seem to work well. That does display also a different date like Friday 8 December 2017  instead of Friday 29 December 2017.

Comment: can you tell me $date is object of what?

Comment: Sorry that was quite stupid, forgot to paste it into my question. I updated  my question.